# MongoDB - How to replace only one object from array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-update

I have the following BSON data in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "789",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p2",
     poNumber : "700",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p3",
     poNumber : "889",
  }
]
```

I want to replace the object where `partyName` is "p2" with a new object. I tried this

```js
const user1 = await User.findOneAndUpdate({"array.partyName" :"p2"},{$set:{array:newObject}})
```

It replaces the object "p2" but it deletes the other objects (p1 and p3). I want to keep p1, and p3, but only update the p2 objects.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with the [`$` positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "array.partyName" :"p2" },
  { $set: { "array.$": newObject } }
)
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zRn7wy1Yfh8)